# How to iterate over a list if lists in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dictionary

I have this list:

```py
my_list = [['ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date']]
```

And try to iterate over it in order to get the values and its' positions, like so:

```py
date    1
country 1
date    2
country 1
date    2
```

It should be later stored in a pandas df, values can be different, there is no fix.

Originally it was a list of dictionaries:

```py
my_original_list = [
    [{'name': 'ga:date'}],
    [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}],
    [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]
]

# But I got the values out of it in a list:
my_list = [li['name'] for li in my_original_list]

# the result
my_list = [
    ['ga:date'], 
    ['ga:country', 'ga:date'],
    ['ga:country', 'ga:date']
]
```

Cracked my mind already how to get it, would appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `enumerate` and `flattening` for list of tuples:

```
my_list = [['ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date']]

x = [(b, a) for i in my_list for (a, b) in enumerate(i, 1)]
print (x)
[('ga:date', 1), ('ga:country', 1), ('ga:date', 2), ('ga:country', 1), ('ga:date', 2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['field','listIndex'])
print (df)
        field  listIndex
0     ga:date          1
1  ga:country          1
2     ga:date          2
3  ga:country          1
4     ga:date          2
```

Or if possible change position of columns:

```
x1 = [z for i in my_list for z in enumerate(i, 1)]
print (x1)
[(1, 'ga:date'), (1, 'ga:country'), (2, 'ga:date'), (1, 'ga:country'), (2, 'ga:date')]

df = pd.DataFrame(x1, columns = ['listIndex','field'])
print (df)
   listIndex       field
0          1     ga:date
1          1  ga:country
2          2     ga:date
3          1  ga:country
4          2     ga:date
```

Also if need remove values before `:`:

```
my_list = [['ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date']]

x = [(b.split(':')[-1], a) for i in my_list for (a, b) in enumerate(i, 1)]
print (x)
[('date', 1), ('country', 1), ('date', 2), ('country', 1), ('date', 2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['field','listIndex'])
print (df)
     field  listIndex
0     date          1
1  country          1
2     date          2
3  country          1
4     date          2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate for this:

```py
my_list = [['ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date']]

for sublist in my_list:
    for position, entry in enumerate(sublist):
        print(entry, position + 1)  # +1 to count positions starting at 1 instead of 0.
```

Comment: Just to note that `enumerate(sublist, start=1)` here avoids the `position + 1` each time...

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import pandas

my_list = [['ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date'], ['ga:country', 'ga:date']]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[(sublist[i],i) for sublist in my_list for i in range(len(sublist))], columns=["field", "listIndex"])
```

REsult:

```
        field  listIndex
0     ga:date          0
1  ga:country          0
2     ga:date          1
3  ga:country          0
4     ga:date          1
```